# JOIN statement shows all users who have allocated points - is there a way to also include users that haven't allocated any points?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a school reward system in which members of staff allocate points to students for positive attitude and behaviour.

I have two tables:

**Staff**
`ID`, `Firstname`, `Surname`, `Position`, `Faculty`, `Subject`, `Hours`, `Allocation`

**Transactions**
`Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that shows how many points members of staff have allocated on a weekly basis.

This statement...

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Staff Name`,
  SUM(t.Points) AS `Points Allocated`
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN staff s ON t.Giver_ID = s.ID
WHERE `Datetime` >= '2012-10-08'
GROUP BY t.Giver_ID
ORDER BY `Points Allocated` ASC
```

... displays a list of users that have allocated points that week, and how many.

[image: Reward System - Staff Names and Points Allocated]

**However**, it doesn't show users that have allocated 0 points.

Is there a way of amending my statement to include those users? Possibly be writing the join in reverse, using the `staff` table and joining to `transactions`? I'm not sure where to start unfortunately.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Well, you have thought of turning the join the other way around yourself, have you actually tried to do it?

Comment: No - because I wasn't sure what segment I'd need to actually turn around! I've heard of RIGHT JOINs but I don't think they're what I'm after?

Comment: just a strange thing : you may have transactions without staff (line 4) ? You also need them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you've got to reverse,

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Staff Name`,
  COALESCE(SUM(t.Points), 0) AS `Points Allocated`
FROM staff s
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.Giver_ID = s.ID
WHERE t.Datetime >= '2012-10-08' or t.Datetime IS NULL
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY `Points Allocated` ASC
```

**EDIT**

as suggested by Ianzz, should be faster

```
SELECT
CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Staff Name`,
COALESCE(SUM(t.Points), 0) AS `Points Allocated`
FROM staff s
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.Giver_ID = s.ID and t.Datetime >='2012-10-08'
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY `Points Allocated` ASC
```

or use RIGHT JOIN and group on s.ID (in both case, use a coalesce on SUM(t.Points) if you don't want null values you must also check for "NULL transaction datetime", or use the date predicate in the join

You'll see more LEFT JOIN then RIGHT JOIN, as you can read that as
select all from my principal entity (in the FROM clause), and try to join another where a joining data exists. But both should work the same

Comment: Hi Raphael. Just like @Erik's answer, your statement returns the same results as the statement in my OP.

Comment: One issue Raphael - the query is taking 8 seconds to run! I presume this is because the `Datetime IS NULL` segment forces the query to run on the entire database rather than the subset I'm looking at? Is there a way around this?

Comment: I would put the `t.Datetime >= '2012-10-08'` in the join condition and avoid the `t.Datetime IS NULL` altogether.

Comment: `WHERE COALESCE...` is likely to prevent MySQL from using indexes at all (provided there is actually an index on `t.Datetime` in the first place)

Comment: If it's relevant there are 130,000 rows in the `transactions` table and 130 members of staff.

Comment: @dunc Well, size of data have of course an impact, you should do some Explain queries, and look at your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by the id in the staff table not the id in the transactions table as well as using a right join instead. Since you wish to keep the staff that have "null" in the transaction table.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Staff Name`,
  SUM(t.Points) AS `Points Allocated`
FROM transactions t
RIGHT JOIN staff s ON t.Giver_ID = s.ID
WHERE `Datetime` >= '2012-10-08'
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY `Points Allocated` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks again @Erik. Oddly, that doesn't appear to work. Still only rows with users that have allocated points are displaying. If I change the date to '2012-10-11', i.e. today's date, only 24 members of staff appear as opposed to the 63 in OP.

Comment: Ah, it was the `Datetime IS NULL`!