# Adding indexes to optimise a query, and analysing EXPLAIN results

Tags: mysql

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842068/join-statement-shows-all-users-who-have-allocated-points-is-there-a-way-to-als) in which I explained that I'm trying to get weekly point allocations from members of staff - including those that have allocated zero.

I have two tables:

**Staff** (140 rows) `ID`, `Firstname`, `Surname`, `Position`, `Faculty`, `Subject`, `Hours`, `Allocation`

**Transactions** (140,000 rows) `Transaction_ID`, `Datetime`, `Giver_ID`, `Recipient_ID`, `Points`, `Category_ID`, `Reason`

The SQL statement I've been trying is this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(s.Firstname, " ", s.Surname) AS `Staff Name`,
  COALESCE(SUM(t.Points), 0) AS `Points Allocated`
FROM staff s
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.Giver_ID = s.ID and t.Datetime >='2012-10-08'
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY `Points Allocated` ASC
```

The query works as intended but **it's taking ~6 seconds to run**.

The only `index` I have on either table is their Primary Keys.

The result of a `EXPLAIN` on this query states:

[image: Reward System - EXPLAINed query]

Sadly, I have no idea what that means! How can I go about optimising my query or tables to improve the run-time of this query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Index `t.Giver_ID` and `t.Datetime` and check what happens.

Comment: Ah, well that's a lot quicker.. ! 0.9s now. Is that all I can do @N.B.?

Comment: There are other optimizations like using InnoDB engine and increasing its `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable, so check what engine you're using and simply change the table to InnoDB if it's not InnoDB already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding an index key on the transaction.Giver_Id and also transaction.dateTime